# Autocomplete function argument in shell function

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Have a couple quick bash functions that let me get to folders I use often:

```
function dp() {
    cd ~/Development/Personal/$1
}

function dw() {
    cd ~/Development/Work/$1
}
```

So I can type  `dp some-project` to go directly to a personal project for example. It would be killer if I could get tab-completion working on the function argument so it automatically pulled in filenames from the directory I'm going to navigate to, but I can't seem to figure it out...

Ideally I could just type `dp b{tab}` and get `dp blog` for example, where `blog` is a folder in the `~/Development/Personal/` directory.

Anyone know how to make this work? I'm using ZSH if it matters!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does matter very much which shell you're using.

First, let me mention that you can add often used directories to a "hotlist" that you can then use with `cd`. For instance, you could do this:

```
cdpath=(~/Development/Personal ~/Development/Work)
```

and then, at any point (and from any directory), you should be able to type `cd blog`. Tab completion will work as well.

If you still want to have your own functions for `cd` and add tab completion for them, here's [a very informative article](http://askql.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/zsh-writing-own-completion/) about how to write your own completion functions.

In a nutshell, you create a file in the zsh completion directory, called `_dp`, and add something like this to it:

```
#compdef dp

compadd $(command ls -1 $HOME/Development/Personal 2>/dev/null --color=none | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g')
```

Comment: For a more `zsh`-like method (that avoids parsing `ls`), try `compadd -- $HOME/Development/Personal/*(:t)`.